# refused to connect to mine server error , why?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, vhosts

I have the following configurations:

httpd.conf :

```
Listen 80
Listen 81

<IfModule unixd_module>
User someone
Group admin
</IfModule>
```

vhosts configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerAdmin codenaki@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sites/conlineltd/project/public"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ServerName conlineltd.com
    ServerAlias www.conlineltd.com
    ErrorLog "logs/conlineltd-error-logs"
    CustomLog "logs/conlineltd-custom-logs" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerAdmin codenaki@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sites/beinstyle/project/public"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ServerName beinstyle.com
    ServerAlias www.beinstyle.com
    ErrorLog "logs/beinstyle-error-logs"
    CustomLog "logs/beinstyle-custom-logs" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Permissions in mine project folder: 
[project1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kih0L.png)

Permissions in mine project folder: [project2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW1dD.png)

Hosts file /etc/hosts : Checked with ping command and working!
[hosts configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKzIh.png)

Chrome Browser Network Tab: 
[While trying to connect to the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGaJl.png)

Error log file from apache :

> > [Mon Dec 04 09:05:00.001257 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5426] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
> >     [Mon Dec 04 09:05:00.001427 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5426] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
> >     [Mon Dec 04 09:05:01.001614 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5430] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
> >     [Mon Dec 04 09:05:01.001694 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5430] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
> >     [Mon Dec 04 09:05:01.001777 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 5430] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
> >     [Mon Dec 04 09:05:01.010589 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5430] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.0.23 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
> >     [Mon Dec 04 09:05:01.010927 2017] [core:notice] [pid 5430] AH00094: Command line: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd -E /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'

Need your help please , how can i resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this same issue for my Apache server.

My server used to run successfully without any error or warning. Then one day I started firewalld on my system for some nagios related stuff and got following in my httpd error_logs 'No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor'

Please check if firewalld or any similar process is running.

Restart your server after disabling firewalld(or any other in your case) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

From the configuration mentioned above, i dont see any entry related to "www.example.com:443" as seen in the logs.
Whats' the URL used to access the website and logging doesnt seems relevant, share the entry from access logs and error logs when you try to access the site.
Need to check few things : is the certificate expired and does the CN name match with websites' hostname ?